# como capturar los elementos hijos (divs) que hay en dos secciones a la vez y copiarlos en otro lado (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema tengo que capturar los elementos que hay en la seccion "active" y "completed" y pasar los a la seccion "all"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
let elemts = d.querySelectorAll(".elemt-list");

for (let i = 0; i < elemts.length; i++) {
            fragment = d.createElement("template");
    fragment =elemts[i]
    fragmentClone = fragment.cloneNode(true)
    d.querySelector(".all-jobs").appendChild(fragmentClone)
}
```

este  es el código que tengo y funciona mas o menos me hace la capia bien pero solo la primera y ya la segunda vez me genera esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que contiene la seccion active
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto la sección completed
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La ultima imagen no es de la seccion completed, si te fijas esta seleccionada la pestana active y no la pestana completed. al igual que la penultima.

Comment: Ah si siento, la sección completed cambien tiene un solo pequeño texto y eso es todo

Comment: Parece que no estás utilizando ningún framework especial... ¿podrías entonces generar un jsfiddle o similar donde poder reproducir tu problema y ayudarte?